# create coupon programmatically

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, coupon

How to create rule  and action in shopping cart price rule in magento programmatically for the condition subtotal equal to or greater than 500.

[Here Image that condition i want to write programmatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzk1n.png)
like that:

```
conditions => array(
                        array(
                            'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
                            'aggregator' => 'all',
                            'value' => 1,
                            'new_child' => null
                        )
                    )
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirements in more details

Comment: What you want to accomplish with this since magento by default provide this features

Comment: I don't know why you need to create it programmatically but for reference you can check this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmatically-create-apply-and-delete-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento/)

Comment: On customer dashboard, I will provide a button to create a coupon code on sale of some amount on his/him account for first time. That will be share to his friend and get discount on shopping cart price above some amount. the above code apply for the all cart item price and get discount.